# How to remove empty space in a input field and re-assign the trim value back

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email, trim

I'm doing a email validation; in the email field, user may put empty space.

So I've decide to `$trim` the input value and re-assign to input field.

It works normally without any issue, but when I use the space bar couple of time and focus out from the input and turn back, the entered space there in the input field.

Event though I am trimming each of the `input` -  I don't know why the space being with `input` field.

Any correct approach please?

here is my try:

```
$('#email').on('input change',function(){
    this.value = $.trim(this.value); //re-assigning trimmed value, but not works when enterning space and focus out. when focus in the space being in the input
    validateEmail.init(this.value);
    if(validateEmail.done()){
        console.log('this is correct');
    }
});

//enter some space and focus out, then come back to input field you can see white spaces in the field
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/SG6YN/1/)

Comment: Do you really need to remove every space in the input box? Why don't you just trim it when passing it to your email validation? (`validateEmail.init($.trim(this.value));`)

Comment: Works fine in FF but not in chrome

Comment: I would like to avoid the whitespace basically, because this is email address. again user can copy paste some unwanted white spaces too.. it became very lengthy in input field.

Comment: now code is updated and now it is working with multiple space in start and in end it will remove all the spaces try this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey i gone through your example..

i have changed the binding in it and it is working as expected...

```
$('#email').on('keyup  change',function(){

     var text = $.trim($(this).val() )
     this.value="";      
     this.value=text;

    validateEmail.init(this.value);
    if(validateEmail.done()){
        console.log('this is correct');
    }
});
```

working example:-http://jsfiddle.net/SG6YN/10/

now if user will try to paste text with space then it will remove those spaces..

thanks

Comment: So, according to you `input` has the issue? I tried not working as expected. please test in chrome browser pelase

Comment: hey i have updated the code for it... you can check now it will remove all the spaces from start and end

Comment: Yes, it's working. I updated your code using Rohand idea as like this:
`var value = $.trim(this.value).replace(/\s+/g,'');` - works fine

Answer (score 1):

Restrict user to entering space in the field

```
$('#email').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 32) // 32 is the ASCII value for a space
            e.preventDefault();
    });
```

But if user copy and paste whitespace containing text then it doesnot work. So add following code on your onChange function

```
$('#email').on('input change',function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, ''));
    validateEmail.init(this.value);
    if(validateEmail.done()){
        console.log('this is correct');
    }
});
```

The working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YjTQ8/)

Comment: try to add multiple space in start and paste it in the text box  it will not work...

Comment: It is working fine. I tested in chrome, mozilla. In which browser it is not working

Comment: try this key word in chrome "   text    " ignore the " from it(it has 3 space in start and in end)